# How to find 2 unknown components of 3 collinear 3D points?

Tags: geometry, vectors

I've been given the question

"The points A(5,-3,z), B(1,3,11) and C(x,15,27) are collinear. Find the values of x and z."

However, the course material only covered proving collinearity of two vectors, I wouldn't even know how to determine if 3 points are collinear. So it then follows that I don't know how to set up any equation where I can solve for the unknown variables.

So I'm wondering either how to prove that 3 points or collinear (and from there I'll try to set up an equation where I can solve for the unknown variables) or simply just how I solve this specific problem.

Comment: see please this  http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=496188

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208577/find-if-the-points-are-collinear  this may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three points gives you two vectors; and, the three points are colinear if and only if these two vectors are parallel!  Consider the vectors
$$
\vec{u}=B-A=\langle-4,6,11-z\rangle\qquad\text{and}\qquad\vec{v}=C-B=\langle x-1,12,16\rangle.
$$
What values of $x$ and $z$ will make these two vectors parallel?

Comment: from there clearly  $x-1=-8$ or  $x=-7$ and  $11-z=8$ or  $z=3$

Comment: @datodatuashvili Exactly right!

Comment: and you +1 for elegant solution

Comment: One question, these two vectors clearly don't overlap, but are still following the same "line". Are they collinear or not? Would C-A be collinear?

Comment: Vectors being "colinear" doesn't really make much sense, since we generally consider vectors to not have a fixed start point. (They describe _relative motion_.)  That's why I said "parallel" for the vectors, rather than "colinear".  I don't know what you mean by the last question, either: would $C-A$ be collinear with _what_?

Comment: Well, would the vector resulting from B-A and the one resulting from C-A be collinear. And well, this is course-material as per Canadian grade 12 curriculum. I don't think they'd include a chapter on collinearity and coplanarity of vectors if the concept itself didn't make mathematical sense.

Comment: I wasn't saying the concept doesn't make sense -- I was saying that I disagree with the terminology!  At any rate: yes, $B-A$ and $C-A$ would be colinear.  Try drawing three sets of points in a few different ways -- some that lie on a line and that don't -- and draw the vectors connecting them.  Maybe that will make the connection clearer.

Comment: Oh, I already got it. I just asked that question to confirm I understood it right, which I did. So no problems there! I just didn't know how to find out if 3 points were collinear.

Comment: Actually, one more question: Would vectors have to overlap to be considered collinear? As in, would $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ in this example be collinear? (just disregard that you disagree with the terminology for a second)

Comment: You'll have to look at how they've defined colinearity of vectors.  My assumption is that they just mean that they are parallel, in which case it does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

If $A,B,C$ are collinear, then $\vec{AB}=k\vec{BC}$ for some scalar $k$.